# Captain Jean-Luc Picard's, "Make it so!"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

"Star-Trek" aficionados ("The Next Generation" 1987-1994) may recall that in trying circumstances, Captain Picard would accept advice, from crew-members, with a "Make it so!".

In Latin could this be one word, an imperative:

> "fac(ite)!" = "Make (it so)"?

I suspect that this is too blunt, even for Latin cf. the English, "Give!"; the French, "Donne!".

Therefore, adding an accusative direct object and an adverb:

> "fac id vero!" = "Make it in fact (so)!".

Is that correct?

[Interesting to note with Latin imperatives: they were not always used in a blunt or rude manner. As Draconis has indicated, in earlier Qs., imperatives appeared in prayers and in an advisory capacity. An example from Allen & Greenough section 580[d]1:

> "fac mihi esse persuasum" = "Suppose that I am persuaded of that." (N.D. 1.75).

The usually blunt "fac" (above) becomes the suggestion, "suppose that".]

EDIT 1/11/2021:

Thanks to Sebastian for the quote from Seneca:

> "ita fac, mi Lucili..." = "Act thus, my dear Lucilius...";

clearly spoken with great warmth.

With Latin imperatives, an assumption is that much may have depended on the tone-of-voice?

Comment: Upvoted for spanning five millennia with uncounted empires and federations in one question ;-). I'm looking forward to the first Klingon -> Latin question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Genesis 1:7 (and other verses):

> And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under
> the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: **and it
> was so**. (KJV)

In Latin:

> Et fecit Deus firmamentum, divisitque aquas, quae erant sub
> firmamento, ab his, quae erant super firmamentum. **Et factum est
> ita**.

**Factum** is the perfect of both **[facio](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=f%C4%83c%C4%ADo&la=la&can=f%C4%83c%C4%ADo0)** (active) and **fio** (passive).

Had Picard spoken Latin, "Make it so!" might have been **Fiat ita!**

Comment: Also cf. Seneca min., [Epistulae morales 1,1,1](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sen/seneca.ep1.shtml): *Ita fac, mi Lucili: ...*

Comment: [*by fiat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiat) is still used in English and fits perfectly.

Comment: Would it depend on context/audience? Eg, "Run, slave!" but "Please hurry,  my friend!"

Comment: @TheHonRose the impersonal form given here essentially translates to "so let it be done." Unless you are a starship captain (or pharaoh) that's probably no way to talk to people. The ordinary imperative is pretty neutral, suitable for any recipient from slave to god, but for making polite entreaties, Latin offers a number of [more elaborate options](https://latinitium.com/how-to-ask-politely-in-latin/) as well.

Comment: Is there any reason **Sic** wouldn't work? I feel like it carries most of the same meaning as **ita**.

Comment: @Nickimite: I agree. I came up with **ita** because of the parallel with Genesis. And I think the double vowel pair has a nice ring to it.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel - thank you, that's interesting. :-)